# Identify duplicates in a group with one value being different

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE TEMPDB
go

IF OBJECT_ID(N'#TEST', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.#TEST


CREATE TABLE #TEST
(NAME VARCHAR(50),
line int,
RANKS INT)
INSERT INTO #TEST
(name, line,RANKS)
VALUES
('Tom',1, 1), --keep
('Tom',2, 1),--keep
('Toms',1, 0), --keep
('Toms',2, 0),--keep
('Dave',1, 0),--delete
('Dave',2, 0),--keep
('Dave',1, 1),--keep
('TIm',1,1),--keep
('TIm',1,0),--delete
('Matt',1,0),--delete
('Matt',1,1)--keep
```

- if the same name and line are falling under different ranks, then I need to delete the onde falling under rank '0' and if the same person with the same line is falling under different ranks, then the one under rank 0 should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
delete t1
  from #TEST t1
 where exists(select *
                from #TEST t2
               where t2.NAME = t1.NAME
                 and t2.line = t1.line
                 and t2.RANKS <> t1.RANKS)
   and t1.RANKS = 0;
```